# Efeito visual ao clicar o botão some quando atribuo um background

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou tentando fazer um botão simples em uma aplicação Android. Ao inserir o botão os efeitos funcionaram normalmente, mas após realizar a mudança da cor de fundo, o efeito ao clicar no botão sumiu, ficando estático.

Gostaria de saber qual propriedade utilizo para resolver isso.

Meu botão está implementado da seguinte forma:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TEST"
    android:background="#2780E3"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso você precisa criar um `selector` para o seu botão, um novo estilo, por exemplo.

só na sua pasta drawable clicar com direito, ir em novo seleciona `xml` o nome você escolhe nesse caso `selector_button.xml`

```
/res/drawable/selector_button.xml
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light"></item>


</selector>
```

Lembre-se de colocar cores diferente para dar o efeito.

E no seu botão você informa esse `selector` no `backgroud`

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
/>
```

Os códigos de cores você obtém aqui 
http://html-color-codes.info/Codigos-de-Cores-HTML/ 
http://www.ufpa.br/dicas/htm/htm-cor2.htm

Comment: @thiago deu certo

Comment: Olá Rodolfo! Desculpe a demora. Eu tentei criar o arquivo XML onde me disse, mas ele cria sempre fora.
E o conteúdo do arquivo deve ser só esse que me mandou?
Obrigado desde já pela resposta!!

Comment: Rodolfo, consegui criar o arquivo, mas ao tentar rodar a aplicação ocorre o seguinte erro
http://pastebin.com/0fhJJBzZ

Comment: adiciona mais deu seu código erro poder outra coisa

Comment: Activity: http://pastebin.com/NHwsErNv
Selector_Button: http://pastebin.com/BUUGLDbi
Erro: http://pastebin.com/0fhJJBzZ

Comment: @Thiago olhe a edição e confira se vai dar certo

Comment: Jóia, agora deu certo!